# BeautifulSoup: How to replace value in an element with an element tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say that I have this piece of HTML:

```
<p>This text is my <a href="#">text</a><p>
```

How do I replace the first "text" with an anchor element, so the result becomes:

```
<p>This <a href="#">text</a> is my <a href="#">text</a><p>
```

I basically want to replace a substring in a NavigableString with a Tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question has two parts:

1. Turning the single NavigableString "This text is my" into a NavigableString, a Tag, and another NavigableString.
2. Replacing the NavigableString "This text is my" with the three new elements.

The answer to #1 depends on your situation. Specifically it depends on how you determine what part of the text needs linking. I'll use a regular expression to find the string "text":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = '<p>This text is my <a href="#">text</a><p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
original_string = soup.p.contents[0]

print(original_string)
# "This text is my "

import re
this, text, is_my = re.compile("(text)").split(original_string)
```

Now for #2. This is not as easy as it could be, but it's definitely possible. First, Turn `text` into a `Tag` containing the link text:

```
text_link = soup.new_tag("a", href="#")
text_link.string = text
```

`re.split()` turned `this` and `is_my` into ordinary Unicode strings. Turn them back into `NavigableString`s so they can go back into the tree as elements:

```
this = soup.new_string(this)
is_my = soup.new_string(is_my)
```

Now use `replace_with()` and `insert_after` to replace the old element with the three new elements:

```
original_string.replace_with(this)
this.insert_after(text_link)
text_link.insert_after(is_my)
```

Now your tree should look the way you want it to:

```
print(soup.p)
# <p>This <a href="#">text</a> is my <a href=""></a></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the text of NavigableString, modify it, build new object model from modified text and then replace old NavigableString with this object model:

```
data = '<p>This text is my <a href="#">text</a><p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
original_string = soup.p.contents[0]
new_text = unicode(original_string).replace(' text ', '<a href="#">text</a>')
original_string.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(text))
```